# Custom function in Access is returning type conversion error

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I am creating a custom function in Access which check 2 fields to see if there is a value in them and returns an answer depending on which field has values.

Half of it works, however I am getting a type conversion error after the query when trying to use the custom function.

There can be 4 results, all of which returns a different answer.

1) Field 1 is Empty & Field 2 is empty = Function returns nothing.

2) Field 1 is Empty & Field 2 has a value = function returns text string "Delete"

3) Field 1 has a Value & Field 2 is empty = function returns text string "New"

4) Field 1 has a value & Field 2 has a value = Check if Values are the same

4a) If value is the same = function returns text string "Match"

4b) If value is different = function returns text string "Update"

I tried to use a case select to determine which field is empty and which field isn't, 
however I resorted to using If statements as I wasn't getting the results I was after.

Currently the half that does work is when it compares the 2 values and returns "Match" and "Update".
The half the doesn't work is when it needs to return "Delete" or "New".  It's like it's not able to determine if the fields are empty.

I tried using IsEmpty, IsNull and Field = ""

Here is my code:

```
Public Function BarcodeCheck(DBTPART As String, SUPPBC As String)

If IsEmpty(DBTPART) And IsEmpty(SUPPBC) Then
    BarcodeCheck = ""
End If

If IsEmpty(DBTPART) And Not IsEmpty(SUPPBC) Then
    BarcodeCheck = "NEW BC"
End If

If Not IsEmpty(DBTPART) And IsEmpty(SUPPBC) Then
    BarcodeCheck = "DELETE BC"
End If

If Not IsEmpty(DBTPART) And Not IsEmpty(SUPPBC) Then
    If DBTPART = SUPPBC Then
        BarcodeCheck = "MATCH"
    Else
      BarcodeCheck = "UPDATE BC"
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the **parameters of your function** which are declared as `String`

```
Public Function BarcodeCheck(DBTPART As String, SUPPBC As String)
```

If the fields `DBTPART` and `SUPPBC` can contain `Null` then you have to declare the parameters in your UDF as `Variant`. In Visual Basic, the only data type that can contain `Null` is the `Variant`. Then in your UDF use `IsNull()` function to compare field value to `Null`.

So the function *should work* when parameters are of type `Variant`. *(And maybe you can use `If-Then-ElseIf`?)*

```
Public Function BarcodeCheck(DBTPART As Variant, SUPPBC As Variant)

    If IsNull(DBTPART) And IsNull(SUPPBC) Then
        BarcodeCheck = "EMPTY123"

    ElseIf IsNull(DBTPART) And Not IsNull(SUPPBC) Then
        BarcodeCheck = "NEW BC"

    ElseIf Not IsNull(DBTPART) And IsNull(SUPPBC) Then
        BarcodeCheck = "DELETE BC"

    ElseIf Not IsNull(DBTPART) And Not IsNull(SUPPBC) Then
        If DBTPART = SUPPBC Then
            BarcodeCheck = "MATCH"
        Else
          BarcodeCheck = "UPDATE BC"
        End If
    End If

End Function
```